# Rails devise registration two ways after sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want `devise` to redirect to specific controller index action( or specific page) after user is sign_up.

In detail, i have an app with 2 ways to sign-up : for the `client` and for the `Professor` . Actually, the 2 type use the same registration page, it works very nice but when they sign_up they are automatically redirect  to the same page ...
So, i want to change the way like this :
- when user click on `I want to become Professor` i want to register (full name, mail, password) and redirect after sign_up to the `Professor` dashboard 
- and when user click on `Client` i want to register with the "same way" BUT in the end, i want to redirect to the `client's dashboard`.

So, i started to change `devise.rb` to change this

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days (automatically login after sign_up)
```

And in my `RegistrationsController`, i override the `after_sign_up_path_for` to have something like

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if 'user is Prof'
    redirect_path_professor 
  else
    redirect_path_client
  end
end
```

but how can i check (in condition) if user click on `Prof.` or `Client` ?. Its the same resource (registration) ^^
Thanks

Comment: send `prof` or `client` from your form and check at registration

Comment: It comes down to how you distinguish between Professor and Client on model level? And I think, in `RegistrationsController` you will be able to find the type from resource object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using only one link, then let the user selects his role in the registration view?

If you really want two links for the same view, you should pass the role in a param (something link `link_to 'Becoming a Professor', new_registration_path(role: 'professor')`, then add an hidden_field in your registration form with the value of the param.

`= f.input :role, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: params[:role] }`

But don't forget to validate the content of the params to avoid the bad values sent by teasing users

Also, `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` should be in application_controller. You'll need a column in users to specify the role, and your method will looks like something like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || (resource.role.professor? ? professor_dashboard_url : user_dashboard_url(resource))
end
```

Comment: Thank's escanxr for your reply, it seems it's a good way to solve my pb, but, sorry i don't see exactly where to put the :role params ? ...

Comment: You'll have different actions according to the user's role (client or professor), so you have to keep this value in users table in your DB. It will be easier to manage the views and actions according to the user's role! If you don't save this value, you'll never know if the user is a professor or a customer